# Fetching Relative Attributes by Xpath

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, html-select

In the dropdown list below, Im trying to select and echo the results of the data-balance attributes assigned to the data-store attribute labeled "Depot Spot" using xpath. I tried the following xpath  but its only showing the text results of the first "Depot Spot" option. What am i missing?

```
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header"><button class="close dialog-close" type="button" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
<h4 class="modal-title"></h4> 
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;//select[@name='giftcard']/option[@data-store='Depot Spot'][@data-balance]</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;Result im getting= Depot Spot<span class="message">: 6010 ($34.25)</span></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</p>
       &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;       But the results should be Depot Spot $34.25
Depot Spot $91.60
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
Depot Spot $9.46
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 
</div>

    <div class="modal-body"><form><input name="action" type="hidden" value="orderAssignGiftcard" /> 
    <input name="orderId" type="hidden" value="139903" />
    <div class="text-center">
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div class="form-group">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="form-group"><label>Gift Cards</label><select class="form-control giftcard-selector" name="giftcard">
    <option value="81695" data-store="Depot Spot" data-number="6010" data-pin="3591" data-balance="34.25">Depot Spot: 9808 ($34.25)</option>
    <option value="81651" data-store="Sunnys" data-number="06074" data-pin="0939" data-balance="8.31001">Sunnys: 9808 ($8.31)</option>
    <option value="81693" data-store="Marvies" data-number="10162" data-pin="5399" data-balance="53.67">Marvies: 5399 ($53.67)</option>
    <option value="81694" data-store="HappyOnes" data-number="10162" data-pin="7011" data-balance="59.95">HappyOnes: 7011 ($59.95)</option>
    <option value="81648" data-store="Depot Spot" data-number="3487" data-pin="7120" data-balance="91.6">Depot Spot: 3487 ($91.60)</option>
    <option value="81636" data-store="Depot Spot" data-number="03371" data-pin="7231" data-balance="9.46">Depot Spot: 03371 ($9.46)</option>
    </select></div>
    </form>
    <div>&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: please add more of your code.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need such complicated xpath. This should make the job as well. You can collect data-store and data-balance values to separate lists if you wish.

```
List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
WebElement dropdown = driver.findElement(By.Name("giftcard"));
dropdown.click(); // to make the options visible
List<WebElement> options = dropdown.findElements(By.TagName("option"));
for (WebElement option: options) {
    String dataStore = option.getAttribute("data-store");
    String dataBalance = option.getAttribute("data-balance");
    results.add(dataStore + "\\$" + dataBalance);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To select the option with text as **Depot Spot: 9808 ($34.25)** from the dropdown you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *cssSelector* and `selectByVisibleText()`:

  ```
  new Select(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("select.form-control.giftcard-selector[name='giftcard']")))).selectByVisibleText("Depot Spot: 9808 ($34.25)");
  ```
- Using *xpath* and `selectByValue()`:

  ```
  new Select(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//select[@class='form-control giftcard-selector' and @name='giftcard']")))).selectByVisibleText("Depot Spot: 9808 ($34.25)");
  ```

Further, to print print the value of the `data-balance` attributes assigned to the data-store value or innerText starting with **Depot Spot** you can use Java8's [`stream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) and [`map()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) you can use the following solution:

- Using *cssSelector* and `data-store` attribute:

  ```
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.cssSelector("select.form-control.giftcard-selector[name='giftcard'] option[data-store='Depot Spot']"))).stream().map(element->element.getAttribute("data-balance")).collect(Collectors.toList()));
  ```
- Using *xpath* and text `Depot Spot:`:

  ```
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//select[@class='form-control giftcard-selector' and @name='giftcard']//option[starts-with(., 'Depot Spot')]"))).stream().map(element->element.getAttribute("data-balance")).collect(Collectors.toList()));
  ```